# while converting number "0.006" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance

Tags: web3js

When I use the code, I will get an error 'while converting number "0.006" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported.'

How can I correct it ?

```
const aWeiValue = 2

const bWeiValue = web3.utils.toWei('0.003', 'mwei')

const totalWeiValue = web3.utils.toBN(aWeiValue).mul(web3.utils.toBN(bWeiValue)).toString()

const totalValue = web3.utils.fromWei(web3.utils.fromWei(totalWeiValue, 'mwei'),'ether') // here

return totalValue
```

Answer (score 0):

BN.js doesn't support decimals.

So instead of converting "0.003 Mwei" to wei, you'll need to count in wei directly.

```
const aWeiValue = 2;

// 0.003 Mwei == 3000 wei
const bWeiValue = 3000;

const totalWeiValue = web3.utils.toBN(aWeiValue).mul(web3.utils.toBN(bWeiValue)).toString()
```

Comment: thank you, but I need change from wei to ether at last

Comment: @BenChuan You can use the `fromWei()` function to return the ETH amount, just like in the snippet in your question... The issue is passing decimals as an input. But they are completely fine as an output.